# "Method onKeyDown is never used" in Android Webview

Tags: android, android-webview

What's wrong with this? The method `onKeyDown` is never being used in my program.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:

        // back button is pressed.. Do your stuff here
        if(myWebView!=null)
        {
            if(myWebView.canGoBack())
            {
                myWebView.goBack();
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I want to navigate through history of webview using this. But this isn't working apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Please override [onBackPressed](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29), as described  [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html).

Comment: Also feel the need to mention that i am using this in fragment not activity. If this code will work for only activity then how to implement the same thing for a fragment? My webviews are inside Fragments.